# access css class that's on same level as

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to change the value of a class when the user selects a radio button.

I currently got the following structure:

```
<div class="chat-box">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <label> Name </label>
    <ol class="discussion">
        <li class="other">
          <div class="avatar">
            <img src="robert.jpg" />
          </div>
          <div class="messages">
            <p>Yesh finally een nice interface met goede chats.</p>
            <p>Nu nog een mooi font</p>
            <time datetime="2009-11-13T20:00">Bas • 51 min</time>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="self">
          <div class="avatar">
            <img src="robert.jpg" />
          </div>
          <div class="messages">
            <p>Uhu</p>
            <time datetime="2009-11-13T20:14">37 mins</time>
          </div>
        </li>

  </ol>

  <input type="text" placeholder="type here your message" class="chat-input">

</div>
```

Whenever the user selects the radio button, I want to hide the `discussion` and `chat-input`.

I can currently hide the `.discussion` but I can't seem to find a fitting operator to hide the `chat-input` class.

This is my working css:

```
.chat-box > input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .discussion, {display:none;}
```

I've tried `discussion::after` but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the same [Sibling `~` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors):

> .chat-box > input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .chat-input

```css
.chat-box > input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .discussion, .chat-box > input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ .chat-input {display:none;}
```

```html
<div class="chat-box">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <label>Name</label>
  <ol class="discussion">
    <li class="other">
      <div class="avatar">
        <img src="robert.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="messages">
        <p>Yesh finally een nice interface met goede chats.</p>
        <p>Nu nog een mooi font</p>
        <time datetime="2009-11-13T20:00">Bas • 51 min</time>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="self">
      <div class="avatar">
        <img src="robert.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div class="messages">
        <p>Uhu</p>
        <time datetime="2009-11-13T20:14">37 mins</time>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <input type="text" placeholder="type here your message" class="chat-input">
</div>
```

Comment: @bdv when you separate by a comma it just make a total different selector doesn't depend of the previous one